# I have to obtain the user's birth month in int form and store as variable for print out later

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is the code I have.

//input

```
    System.out.println("Using numbers, in what month were you born? ");

    String **userMonth** = input.nextLine();

// also tried int **userMonth** = input.nextInt();
```

It does not work either way.

userMonth will not "activate?" (sorry noob and don't know all terms)

When tried to call later in program error:

```
    if (userMonth < 3) {
    System.out.println("Your vacation home is a van down by a river!"); 
    }
```

//userMonth cannot be resolved to variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: No my code is not making userMonth into an object where when I try to reference it later it does not connect to the variable.

Comment: Could you please post the full code. are you using `userMonth<3` in the same method where you do `String userMonth = input.nextLine();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very odd that your variables are showing up as `**varName**` instead of `varName`.

- First use:

```
int userMonth = 0; // initialize variable.
userMonth = input.nextInt();
```

> But it does not consume the newline ('ENTER').

- Therefore, immediately after, consume the newline character via:

```
input.nextLine();
```

- Also make sure Scanner was declared as

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

- Don't forget to close the scanner at the end of program

```
input.close();
```